# Div ID changed on screen load but new id script not triggering on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a randomised winner popup. 
I have gotten to the point where when the page loads, one of the 3 divs id's is replaced by winner.

The issue is when clicking the div with the id winner, it does not trigger the jquery associated with it.

Is there anything I can change to fix this issue?

A sample of the code I am using is included below.

```js
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#left").click(function(){
                $("#limg").attr('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/175');
            });

            $("#center").click(function(){
                $("#cimg").attr('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/175');
            });

            $("#right").click(function(){
                $("#rimg").attr('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/175');
            });

            $("#winner").click(function(){
                $("#wimg").attr('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/190');
                $("#winbox").css('display','block');
                $("#winbox").css('z-index','2');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```css
<style>
    #winbox {display:none; background-color:red; color:white; padding:20px;}
</style>
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="winbox">WINNER</div>
    <div id="left"><img id="limg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/145"></div>
    <div id="center"><img id="cimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
    <div id="right"><img id="rimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/155"></div>

        <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var selector = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
            if (selector == 1) document.getElementById("left").id = ("winner"), document.getElementById("limg").id = ("wimg");
            else if (selector == 2) document.getElementById("center").id = ("winner"), document.getElementById("cimg").id = ("wimg");
            else if (selector == 3) document.getElementById("right").id = ("winner"), document.getElementById("rimg").id = ("wimg");
        }
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I realise I haven't added the jquery link in the snippet but I have in the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved

`$("#winner").click(function() {
      $("#wimg").attr('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/190');
      $("#winbox").css('display', 'block');
      $("#winbox").css('z-index', '2');`

to run after random div selection instead of page load.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#left").click(function() {
      $("#limg").attr('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/175');
    });

    $("#center").click(function() {
      $("#cimg").attr('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/175');
    });

    $("#right").click(function() {
      $("#rimg").attr('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/175');
    });
    
  });
```

```css
#winbox {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="winbox">WINNER</div>
  <div id="left"><img id="limg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/145"></div>
  <div id="center"><img id="cimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
  <div id="right"><img id="rimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/155"></div>

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var selector = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
      console.log(selector)
      if (selector == 1) document.getElementById("left").id = ("winner"), document.getElementById("limg").id = ("wimg");
      else if (selector == 2) document.getElementById("center").id = ("winner"), document.getElementById("cimg").id = ("wimg");
      else if (selector == 3) document.getElementById("right").id = ("winner"), document.getElementById("rimg").id = ("wimg");
      $("#winner").click(function() {
      $("#wimg").attr('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/190');
      $("#winbox").css('display', 'block');
      $("#winbox").css('z-index', '2');
    });
    }
  </script>
</body>
```